# Manhattan distance with impassible tiles - python

Tags: python, manhattan

I have a 2D map (represented as list of lists) in python. Each cell has a boolean value: if the value is `True` the user can walk through the tile, and if the value is `False` the user can't walk through it.

Is there a function that can help me find the shortest path (or even just its length, similar to Manhattan distance) between two tiles (that does not include impassible tiles)?

Comment: This question seems to have nothing to do with programming or Python, but is a general algorithmic or mathematical question. Since you have no code to share, or any errors, StackOverflow might be the wrong site.

Comment: This seems like a typical path finding problem, for which there are Dijkstra's algorithm, A-star, and many other methods